# Wrong limit: Limit[(1 + (-1)^n/n)^n, n -> Infinity]=1 (Mathematica 10.4 and W-Alpha)

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, bugs, symbolic

**Bug introduced in year 2002 (?) and fixed in 11.0**

---

Since $(1-\frac{1}{n})^n\to 1/e$ and $(1+1/n)^n\to e$, the sequence $(1+\frac{(-1)^n}{n})^n$ has no limit as $n\to\infty$, but has limits for odds and even numbers. If $n$ were taken to be real, there would be oscillation through the interval $[1/e,e]$. However, Mathematica 10.4 as well as Wolfram Alpha give

```
Limit[(1 + (-1)^n/n)^n, n -> Infinity]=1
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Please do not use the `bugs` tag when posting new questions.  This tag is special and it is meant to be added by someone else than the original poster, only after the bug was confirmed by the community.

Comment: Weird. But okay, when we are already discussing tags: do you think it would be useful to create a tag "Limit"? I can't do so myself, but I think the tag "symbolic" alone describes this question very poorly.

Comment: I thought that tag (`limit`) existed, and was surprised to see it missing. I thought it *did* exist in the past ... BTW yes, it looks pretty much like a bug. I'll let someone else put the tag back.

Comment: for me, it's a bug.

Comment: For now, the tag I added is sufficient, and I see no need for more specialized tags.

Comment: I wonder what it's doing behind the scene in order to arrive at such an answer.

Comment: Bugs tag restored.

Comment: maybe there ought to be a `bugs-suspected` tag or the like.

Comment: Turns out this is over 14 years old. Good thing it was reported before it got a drivers license and started doing real damage. (I'm not really intending to take a cavalier attitude toward bugs, it's just that I am amazed this went under the radar for so long).

Comment: @Daniel where do you have the 14 years from?

Comment: CVS history (after tracking down the offending bit of code).

Answer (score 5):

It is definitely a bug.

And it can be formuated even more sharply.

```
$Version

(* Out[156]= "10.1.0  for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (March 24, 2015)" *)
```

Define

```
f[n_, a_] := (1 + (-1)^n/n^a)^n
```

If `a>0` the limit exists and is equal to unity. If a == 0 we have the problem of the OP, where one might say that "two alternative limits exist". This is sometimes acknowledged my Mathamtica by indicating an interval in the quantity is to be found for large n. But this does not happen in our case.

But here comes the ultimate shock: Mathematica returns the limit 1 even if `0<a<1`.

Indeed, Mathematica tells us that

```
Table[Limit[f[n, 1/k], n -> \[Infinity]], {k, 2, 5}]

(* Out[117]= {1, 1, 1, 1} *)
```

whereas mathematically none of these limits exist:

The even members diverge like `Exp[n^(1-1/k)]`

```
Table[Limit[(1 + 1/n^((1/k)))^ n, n -> \[Infinity]], {k, 2, 5}]

(* Out[143]= {\[Infinity], \[Infinity], \[Infinity], \[Infinity]} *)
```

and the odd members go to zero

```
Table[
 Limit[(1 - 1/n^((1/k)))^ n, n -> \[Infinity]], {k, 2, 5}]

(* Out[141]= {0, 0, 0, 0} *)
```

Comment: I wrote no such thing. I said the bug had been around for 14 years. I did not state it was well known, or even known. Had it been known, it would have been fixed. I'll trust you to edit the post to reflect the actual remarks.

Comment: @Danile Lichtblau: all refrence to you deleted. Still, I would have expected recognition of my sharper formulation of the bug instead of being downvalued to 0 by somebody.